# Android : LibGDX button

Tags: android, libgdx

How can I create LibGDX button and set touch listener to it?I want to create main menu of my game and put three buttons there (play,settings,about).I tried to do that with `Sprite` but how I saw `Sprite` doesnt have touch listener.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Stage` and `Button` class, something like this:

```
    Button btn = new Button(new SpriteDrawable(yourIdleSprite),
            new SpriteDrawable(yourPressedSprite));
    btn.addListener(new ClickListener() {
        public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
            //your code
        }
    });
    Stage stage= new Stage();
    stage.addActor(btn);
```

There also lots of ways to create your own button class, you can also find a lot of examples in official documentation -> https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki

Comment: I have tried in that way but click listener dont work((

Comment: post your code here, maybe I will able to help. Also maybe you didn't set inputProcessor? Like this:   Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage); - you should set inputProcessor in order to handle clicks.